# Game of Life, java objects

Tags: java

On my program for java programming is not running right. My professor had us download a console.java to help use make a console to display our outputs of the program. I think the program is getting stuck when I am calling the update method and checkCells. My professor said that calling matrix.length for both rows and columns is incorrect but I'm stumped on how to call columns if I am not using matrix.length.

Any input is appreciated

```
import java.util.*;

public class Life {

    private int birthLow = 0;
    private int birthHigh = 0;
    private int liveLow = 0;
    private int liveHigh = 0;
    private boolean[][] matrix;

    public Life(long seed, int rows, int cols, int birthLow2, int birthHigh2, int liveLow2, int liveHigh2) {

        boolean initalMatrix[][] = new boolean[rows][cols];

        seedArray(initalMatrix, rows, cols, seed);

        birthLow = birthLow2;
        birthHigh = birthHigh2;
        liveLow = liveLow2;
        liveHigh = liveHigh2;
        matrix = initalMatrix;

        if ((rows < 1) && (cols < 1)) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Rows must be positive, not " + rows);
        }
        if ((rows > 9) && (cols < 9)) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Rows and cols cant go over 9, not " + rows + cols);
        }
        if (birthLow < 1 || (birthHigh > 9) || (liveLow < 1) || (liveHigh > 9)) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("birth rates can not be below 1 or above 9 " + birthLow + birthHigh);
        }

    }

    public boolean[][] world() {
        boolean[][] matrixClone = matrix.clone();
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            matrixClone[row] = matrix[row].clone();
        }
        return matrixClone;
    }

    public void update() {
        matrix = checkCells(matrix, matrix.length, matrix.length, birthLow, birthHigh, liveLow, liveHigh);
    }

    public static void seedArray(boolean[][] matrix, int rows, int cols, long seed) {
        // generates a random seed to fill the matrix
        Random s = new Random(seed);

        for (int r = 1; r < rows - 1; r++) {
            for (int c = 1; c < cols - 1; c++) {

                boolean x = s.nextBoolean();
                matrix[r][c] = x;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printBoard(boolean[][] matrix, int rows, int cols) {
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {

                if (matrix[r][c] == false && c == 0) {
                    System.out.print("- ");
                } else if (matrix[r][c] == false && c > 0) {
                    System.out.print("- ");
                } else if (matrix[r][c] == true) {
                    System.out.print("# ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean[][] checkCells(boolean[][] matrix, int rows, int cols, int birthLow, int birthHigh,
            int liveLow, int liveHigh) {
        // clones matrix board
        boolean[][] matrixClone = matrix.clone();
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            matrixClone[row] = matrix[row].clone();
        }
        // determines if the living cell is going to live or die
        for (int r = 1; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 1; c < cols; c++) {
                if (neighbors(matrixClone, r, c) < liveLow || neighbors(matrixClone, r, c) > liveHigh || c == 0
                        || r == 0 || c == cols - 1 || r == rows - 1) {
                    matrix[r][c] = false;
                } else if (neighbors(matrixClone, r, c) >= birthLow && neighbors(matrixClone, r, c) <= birthHigh) {
                    matrix[r][c] = true;

                }
            }

        }
        return matrixClone;

    }

    public static int neighbors(boolean[][] matrixClone, int r, int c) {
        int neighbors = 0;
        // checks all neighbors for life or death
        for (int rn = (r - 1); rn <= (r + 1); rn++) {
            for (int cn = (c - 1); cn <= (c + 1); cn++) {
                try {
                    if (matrixClone[rn][cn] == true) {
                        neighbors++;
                    }
                    // catches the array if it checks out the perimeter
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException f) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the relevance of these 100 lines of code? How do they relate to what you are asking? What are you actually asking?

Comment: "how to call columns"?  I don't know what that means.

Comment: when i am calling checkCells in the method update, i use matrix.length twice for filling in the rows and columns of the array. Professor said that using matrix.length twice is not correct. How do i pass rows and columns in the update method?

Comment: The number of elements in a given row is `matrix[row].length`, ie the number of columns in that row. It doesnt have to be a square array (although i believe your implementation it will be).

Comment: I can't pass rows into the update method and into the checkCells parameters. Thats why i was using matrix.length instead of int rows and int cols. but my professor said that matrix.length isnt correct for columns, but is correct for rows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `matrix.length` for columns. You already know that. The reason is that it gives you the number of rows. Instead, just save the values of `row` and `col` and use them.

One way to do that is to make them fields, and initialize them in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Do not initialize a random boolean[][] called initialMatrix. Instead, initialize the boolean[][] matrix that you have in the fields up above (matrix = new boolean[rows][cols]). Then for seedArray, call seedArray(matrix, rows, cols, seed).

Finally, in the update() method, do not use matrix.length, but rather rows and cols.